# Form being submited when not related button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

In my current project, I have a html form which contain a structure like that:

```
  <!-- Tab links -->
  <div class="tab_idioma">
    <button class="tabidioma active" id="en-US-tab" onclick="openIdiomaTab(this);" data-id="en-US">en-US</button>
<button class="tabidioma" id="es-ES-tab" onclick="openIdiomaTab(this);" data-id="es-ES">es-ES</button>
<button class="tabidioma" id="pt-BR-tab" onclick="openIdiomaTab(this);" data-id="pt-BR">pt-BR</button>
  </div>

  <!-- Tab content -->
  <div id="en-US" class="tabcontent_idioma" style="display: block;">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="es-ES" class="tabcontent_idioma" style="display: block;">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="pt-BR" class="tabcontent_idioma" style="display: block;">
    ...
  </div>
```

What's happening is that when I try access the second (or third tab) the form is submitted to the server, before I fil all the fields of the form, persisting incomplete data on the database.

the javascript function which should be called is:

```
function openIdiomaTab(element) {
  // Declare all variables
  var id = element.dataset.id;
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent_idioma");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tabidioma");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById(id+'-tab').className += " active";
}
```

the submission process should be handled by this function:

```
function submit_insert() {
  var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("form"));
  var url = document.getElementById("form").action;

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", url);
  xhr.onload = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('insert').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('table-body').innerHTML = '';
    openTab('listagem-tab', 'listagem');
    load_content();
  };
  xhr.send(formData);
}
```

But this is not happening for this undesired submission. Anyone can give a hint of what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `type` for a `button` is `submit`. If you are using a `button` inside of a `form` for a different reason, you need to explicitly set the `type` to `button` so it won't submit the form:

```
<button type='button'....>
```